# Adding rows in dataframe with function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fill

```
# new empty dataframe to fill
indexes_to_check = pd.DataFrame(columns=['index', 'reason'])

# function which should fill
def add_to_df(index, reason, source):
    for i in indexes:
        row = pd.DataFrame([[i, reason]], columns=['index', 'reason'])
        source = source.append(row)
    return source

# filling a dataframe to further check
add_to_df(df.query('total_images == 0').index, 'no photo', indexes_to_check)
```

**Problem:** If I cast a function **add_to_df** as result I see a temporary dataframe **source** filled as I want but dataframe **indexes_to_check** (which I want to be filled) is still empty.

What should I do to fill **indexes_to_check** but not a temporary dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the loop as `for i in index:` **and** to assign the function to the new object `indexes_to_check = add_to_df(df.query('total_images == 0').index, 'no photo', indexes_to_check)`:

```
# new empty dataframe to fill
indexes_to_check = pd.DataFrame(columns=['index', 'reason'])

# function which should fill
def add_to_df(index, reason, source):
    for i in index:
        row = pd.DataFrame([[i, reason]], columns=['index', 'reason'])
        source = source.append(row)
    return source

# filling a dataframe to further check
indexes_to_check = add_to_df(df.query('total_images == 0').index, 'no photo', indexes_to_check)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# function which should fill
def add_to_df(index, reason, source):
for i in indexes:
    row = pd.DataFrame([[i, reason]], columns=['index', 'reason'])
    source = source.append(row)
return source
```

see your for Loop in this function,
simply replace `for i in indexes :` to `for i in index :`

Your mistake is simple that you are using other parameter .

Answer (score 0):

The 'source' in your function is a local variable and 'indexes_to_check' is not changed.